# How to use MFA for Outlook365 from Thunderbird

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, multi-factor-authentication

I use Thunderbird as an email client. I also have an outlook account that must have MFA enabled. I can log into my outlook account via the browser using the microsoft authenticator mobile app. However when I try to authenticate to my outlook account via Thunderbird using just username and password, it fails (obviously). How can I set up Thunderbird to wait/prompt for MFA authentication? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

DAVMail. http://davmail.sourceforge.net/faq.html. It's a proxy on your network (on my workstation) between O365 Exchange and my local on-Linux Thunderbird. Provides my Thunderbird POP, SMTP, IMAP.

My legacy authentication is our first round of being blocked before Microsoft's hard block in October 2022, therefore I'm pressed to get it working today.

In the Main gateway settings configuration window, choose the Exchange Protocol "O365Interactive" which should provide your usual web-based organisation username/password and THEN Microsoft web popup for MFA authentication.

Only caveat so far: I don't yet have my subfolders appearing in IMAP, I don't even have them in the subscription list yet. Working on that next.